# Is it possible to run fitlibrary tests using the FitNesseSuite JUnit runner?

Tags: java, junit, fitnesse

I already run fitnesse suites outside of the fitnesse server using a test class of the form:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseSuite.class)
@Name("FitNesse.MyAcceptanceTestSuite")
@FitnesseDir("src/it/resources")
@OutputDir("target/fitnesse-results")
@DebugMode(true)
public class JavaFitNesseSuiteIT {
    //
}
```

I've managed to get fitlibrary running on my fitnesse server but when I try to run the fitlibrary-based tests in JUnit they're ignored because they're not using

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
```

Rather they use

```
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer}
```

Is there any way to get them running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `@DebugMode(false)`. When the debug mode is true, it will always try to run the fitnesse tests using `fit.FitServer`.

Without `DebugMode` it runs the FitServer or FitLibraryServer in a new process. Thus is important to define well the classpath (will not use the one in the current process).

I try to run FitNesse first from the project folder:

```
java -jar target/site/fitnesse-20111025.jar -p 8080 -d src/it/resources to make sure the setup is correct.
```